# I'm trying to create a folder but getting the error "npm ERR! code EEXIST"

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a folder but getting the error:

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/tranvanduc/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9f/67
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/tranvanduc/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9f/67'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/tranvanduc/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/9f/67
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/tranvanduc/.npm/_logs/2023-12-02T10_35_14_167Z-debug-0.log

Please can you help me fix this error?

I'm a beginner and I don't have much experience yet.

Comment: I think you are not creating a folder but start new react using "create react app". I suggest you to add command you are executing and  operating system you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my m2 mac when trying to create-react-app.
(npm version at the time : 10.2.4)

Here was my problem displayed on my terminal :

npx create-react-app my-new-app

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/derklein/.npm/_cacache/tmp/bf1fd0d4
npm ERR! dest /Users/derklein/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/64/36/20491eae129c1da7cf5c697c9646f20a84f9b10ddaee630dd7f578974186e9af28e196f2e7b1cd37dbc7cae34463743d9a03c1840bdbf44449d2cd7470fa
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/Users/derklein/.npm/_cacache/tmp/bf1fd0d4' -> '/Users/derklein/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/64/36/20491eae129c1da7cf5c697c9646f20a84f9b10ddaee630dd7f578974186e9af28e196f2e7b1cd37dbc7cae34463743d9a03c1840bdbf44449d2cd7470fa'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/derklein/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/64/36/20491eae129c1da7cf5c697c9646f20a84f9b10ddaee630dd7f578974186e9af28e196f2e7b1cd37dbc7cae34463743d9a03c1840bdbf44449d2cd7470fa
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/derklein/.npm/_logs/2024-02-28T10_57_53_049Z-debug-0.log

---

The solution I've found to fix the problem was simply to write :

sudo npx create-react-app my-new-app

-------- Then Terminal asked me for my password

Password: ******
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app@5.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) Y
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

Creating a new React app in /Users/derklein/Desktop/my-new-app.

---

my-new-app have been created successfully

---

Then, when I tried to create an other react app, this time I had this ERROR message [ERROR message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19diF.png) indicating me to run the sudo chown -R...

I did it and it definitively fixed my problems.

I hope this will help ! :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35717324)